# If $Df(a)$ is non singular and $f \in \mathscr{C}^{1}$, so $f$ is locally one-to-one.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

> Let $A$ be a open in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Let $f: A \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be of class $\mathscr{C}^{1}$.
> If $Df(a)$ is non-singular, there exists an $\alpha>0$ s.t the inequality $$||f(x)-f(y)||\geq \alpha ||x-y||$$holds for all $x,y$ in some open cube $C(a;\epsilon)$ in some open cube $C(a;\epsilon)$ centered at $a$. It follows that $f$ is one-to-one on this open cube.

**My attempt:** Let $E=Df(a)$, so since $\det(Df(a))\not=0$, we have that there exists one matrix $E^{-1}$, such that  $E^{-1}E=EE^{-1}=I_{n}$.

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ by $T(x)=Ex$, so we have that $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $$ ||x-y||=||E^{-1}(Ex-Ey)||\leq n ||E^{-1}||\cdot ||Ex-Ey||,n \in \mathbb{N} \iff \frac{1}{n||E^{-1}||}||x-y||\leq ||Ex-Ey||$$
Now, since $||E^{-1}||> 0$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$, so $2\beta:=\frac{1}{n||E^{-1}||}>0$. Therefore, $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, we have that $$||Ex-Ey||\geq 2\beta ||x-y||$$Let $H: A\subset \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ by $$H(x)=f(x)-Ex$$since $f \in \mathscr{C}^{1}$ and $Ex \in \mathscr{C}^{1}$,  so $H\in \mathscr{C}^{1}$. Therefore $\forall x \in A: DH(x)=Df(x)-D(Ex)=Df(x)-E$. In particular, $DH(a)=Df(a)-E=E-E=0 \implies DH(a)=0$.

***Claim:** Since $H \in \mathscr{C}^{1}$, so we can choose a $\epsilon>0$ such that $\left|DH(x)\right|<\beta$ for $x \in C=C(a;\epsilon)$*

**Question:** How can I prove **claim**?

Thanks @ nicomezi and @peek-a-boo for the explain about my **claim**.

**EDIT:** Since that $H \in \mathscr{C}^{1}$, we can choose $\epsilon>0$ s.t $|DH(x)|<\beta$ for $x \in C(a;\epsilon)$. Now, the TVM applied to the $i^{th}$component function $H$, tells us gives $x,y \in C(a;\epsilon)$, there's a $c \in C(a;\epsilon)$ s.t: $$|H_{i}(x)-H_{i}(y)|\leq ||DH(c)||\cdot ||x-y||= \beta ||x-y||$$

Then, $\forall x, y \in C(a;\epsilon)$, we have
$$\begin{align*}
\beta||x-y||&\geq & ||H(x)-H(y)||\\
&=&||f(x)-Ex-f(y)+Ey||\\
&\geq& ||Ex-Ey||-||f(x)-f(y)||\\
&\geq& 2\beta ||x-y||-||f(x)-f(y)||\end{align*}$$

Now, let $\beta:=\alpha>0$, so we have $$||f(x)-f(y)||\geq 2\alpha ||x-y||-\alpha||x-y||=||x-y||$$So, there exists an $\alpha>0$ s.t $$||f(x)-f(y)||\geq \alpha||x-y||$$holds for all $x,y \in C(a;\epsilon)$.

Is my prove correct, now? Any suggests? Thanks so much.

Comment: Since $H \in \mathcal{C}^1$, $x \mapsto DH(x)$ is continuous (seen as a function between $A$ to the space of continuous linear application over $\mathbb{R}^n$), so is the function $x \mapsto |DH(x)|$

Comment: Can you explain more? I understand that there exists  $M$ s,t $|DH(x)|\leq M$ but, can I use $\beta$ such that $|DH(x)|\leq \beta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $H$ being $C^1$ means that the map $DH:A\to \mathcal{L}(\Bbb{R}^n)$, $x\mapsto DH(x)$ is continuous (where we give the target space some norm $|\cdot|$; usually we give it the operator norm).

Now, rather than writing down the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity, we shall write down the "$\beta$-$\epsilon$" definition (which is of course the same thing but with different symbols). Since $DH:A\to \mathcal{L}(\Bbb{R}^n)$ is continuous at the point $a$, we have:

> For every $\beta>0$, there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $x\in C(a;\epsilon)$, we have $|DH(x)- DH(a)|\leq \beta$.

Now, since you showed $DH(a) = 0$, we have $|DH(x)| \leq \beta$.